# multipliquei o char e imprimiu um número. Como resolvo? Ou será que estou usando errado?

Tags: java, variáveis, char

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EstruturaSequencial004 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        double hora_trabalhada_valor, horas_trabalhadas, salario_bruto;
        char icone = '=';
        
        System.out.print("Digite qual o valor da hora trabalhada em reais (Ex.:5,60): ");
        hora_trabalhada_valor = entrada.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.print("Digite quantas horas foram trabalhadas durante o mês (Ex.:200,5): ");
        horas_trabalhadas = entrada.nextDouble();
        
        salario_bruto = hora_trabalhada_valor * horas_trabalhadas;
        System.out.printf("Salário bruto do mês: %.2f\n", (salario_bruto));
        // descontos: 
        // Após 
        double imposto_de_renda = salario_bruto * 11/100; /* caso use, no modo objetivo (0.89), já daria o 
        resultado, impossibilitando de mostrar oque foi descontado.*/
        System.out.printf("Desconto do Imposto de Renda sobre o salário bruto: %.2f\n", (imposto_de_renda));
        
        double inss = salario_bruto * 8/100;
        System.out.printf("Desconto do INSS sobre o salaário bruto: %.2f\n", (inss));
        
        double sindicato = salario_bruto * 5/100;
        System.out.printf("Desconto do Sindicato sobre o salário bruto: %.2f\n", (sindicato));
        
        System.out.println(icone * 7+"RESUMO"+icone * 7);
        
        double salario_liquido = salario_bruto - (imposto_de_renda + inss + sindicato);
        System.out.printf("Salário bruto: %.2f \nSalário Líquido: %.2f\n", (salario_bruto), (salario_liquido));
        
        double total_descontos = salario_bruto - salario_liquido;
        System.out.printf("Total descontos: %.2f", (total_descontos));
        
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Tente colocar o "icone * 7" entre parênteses, pode ser que assim a linguagem reconheça como algo separado da string de "RESUMO" e aceite imprimir direitinho.